# AngularJS - access elements outside of ng-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a setup with an ng-view (an admin panel) that lets me display orders. I have a search box outside of ng-view that I would like to use to modify my json request.  I've seen some posts on accessing things such as the title but was not able to get them to work - perhaps outdated.

Main app stuff:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.controllers', 'myApp.filters', 'myApp.services', 'myApp.directives', 'ui.bootstrap']).
config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider)       {

$routeProvider.
  when('/', {
    templateUrl: '/partials/order/manage.html',
    controller: 'ManageOrderCtrl'
  }).     
  when('/order/:id', {
   templateUrl: '/partials/order/view.html',
    controller: 'ViewOrderCtrl'
  }).   
  otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Manage controller:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
.controller('ManageOrderCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$dialog', 'config', 'Page', function($scope, $http, $dialog, config, Page) {

  // would like to have search value from input #search available here
  var getData = function() {
    $http.get('/orders').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.orders = data.orders;
    });
  };

getData();
})
```

View:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" >
  <input type="text" id="search">
  <div class="ng-cloak" >
    <div ng-view></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you're going to access stuff outside the `<div ng-view></div>`, I think a better approach would be to create a controller for the outer region as well. Then you create a service to share data between the controllers:

```html
<body ng-app="myApp" >
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <input type="text" id="search">
  </div>
  <div class="ng-cloak" >
    <div ng-view></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

(`ng-controller="MainCtrl"` can also be placed on the `<body>` tag - then the ng-view $scope would be a child of the MainCtrl $scope instead of a sibling.)

Creating the service is as simple as this:

```js
app.factory('Search',function(){
  return {text:''};
});
```

And it's injectable like this:

```js
app.controller('ManageOrderCtrl', function($scope,Search) {
  $scope.searchFromService = Search;
});

app.controller('MainCtrl',function($scope,Search){
  $scope.search = Search;
});
```

This way you don't have to rely on sharing data through the global $rootScope (which is kinda like relying on global variables in javascript - a bad idea for all sorts of reasons) or through a $parent scope which may or may not be present.

I've created a [**plnkr** that tries to show the difference](http://plnkr.co/edit/8LwPRy3ssdT6wWLuvqNB) between the two solutions.

Comment: Almost there - the issue I have is that if I type in the search box and press enter then it just reloads the apps and never gets the search data to the ajax fetch.

Comment: I have ng-submit on the form which calls a function inside of MainCtrl - not sure how to get that to trigger a reload in ManageOrderCtrl.

Comment: This sounds like a different problem than the one describe in original question, but if you could recreate the problem in a plnkr I can give it a go

Comment: Same question really - how can I get search form data to my controller where indicated in the code. But I have it resolved - http://plnkr.co/edit/oFMfu1SvrXyuc5fGZIG2

Answer (score 3):

You can use **scope hierarchies**.

Add an "outer" `ng-controller` definition to your HTML like this:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
```

It will become the $parent scope.  But you do not need to share data by using a service. You don't even need to use the `$scope.$parent` scope.  You can use **[scope hierarchies](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)**.  (See the Scope Hierarchies section on that page).  It is really easy.

In your `MainCtrl`, you may have this:

```
$scope.userName = "Aziz";
```

Then in any controller that is nested within MainCtrl (and does not override the userName in its own scope) will have userName also!  You can use in in the view with {{userName}}.

Comment: initially, assume that we have a login controller and login view in ng-view which is in Main Controller, how should I update the main controller from the data coming up from login view? we need to restart the main controller  too.

Comment: The Main Controller scope is available within a nested scope.  Put a breakpoint in the code and look at the $scope.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

View:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" >
  <input type="text" id="search" ng-model="searchQuery" />
  <div class="ng-cloak" >
    <div ng-view></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Using it in your controller:

```
$http.get('/orders?query=' + $scope.searchQuery).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.orders = data.orders;
});
```

Basically, you can do that with anything INSIDE ng-app...  Move your ng-app to the `html` tag and you can edit the `title` as well!

Comment: This doesn't work, if the view is bound to a controller. seachQuery will not be attached to scope of that controller.