# Angularjs filter search from outside the ng-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I'm trying to do a `full text search` on several `li`.

I've got a:

```
 <input type="text" placeholder="Search..."/ ng-model="query.title">
```

which is not controlled by any controller nor included in the `ng-view`

and

```
 <li class="timeline-blue" ng-repeat="plot in plots | filter:query">
  ...
  {{plot.title}}
  ...
 </li>
```

which is included in a `controller` and in the `ng-view`.

Clearly if I include the `input` inside the `li` HTML **partial** , the `filter` works viceversa in actual situation it does not. 
I'm new to AngularJS and I apologize if I did not try something more, but I'm still getting into *AngularJS approach*

Comment: Looks to me your title has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: ops lol It was an old question I edit instantly sorry!

Comment: Given the information you provided it seems that your controllers (used in `ng-view`) are not prototypically inheriting the `query` model object. You can test for this with a simple $watch inside your `li` controller or by evaluating the `query` object in `li` view (`{{query|json}}`). Either way, I think we'll need a plunker here.

Comment: Yes, It's kinda you said. I found this question that is similar to my issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16028678/angularjs-access-elements-outside-of-ng-view

Comment: Ok it solved my issue, I guess it can be flagged as duplicated.