# possibility to change the background of body in html page

Tags: css, angularjs, html

I have frond end built using angularjs. I have declared the background image for body of the `index.html` page (its same for whole website).

whenever I go to the **new url, a view will be displayed in `ng-view`**.  currently I am planning to change the `background` of only login page.

Whenever i go to the url `localhost:3000/login`, background (of body) should change for only that page. for rest of the page it should remain same.
Is there anyway to do it?

Edit: Right now I have this code in my app.scss

```
 body {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    @include background-image(linear-gradient(#c3c3c3, white 350px));
  }
```

And its common for all the pages. When i load the **login page**, still this background styling will be displayed(which is inherited). Which I want to remove (background: none) for only login page.  Hope it clarifies my question.

Comment: Sound like you want to do something like this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16028678/angularjs-access-elements-outside-of-ng-view
Then you could just access the class attr. and change it to another css-class which has a different URL for the background.

Comment: I did try below: 
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
          angular.element('body').addClass('noBackground');
        });

But initially it loads the earlier background and remove it after some time.

Comment: Then you should do it the other way around, have none as default and only set the background when the app has loaded (except for the login page). Then your login will have no background and when you login you will have the background (since the app has loaded before you login).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

1. changing it in the CSS file
2. changing the 
   `ng-style="{'backgroundimage':'url(typeUrlHere)'}">` inside the desired tag.

Comment: i tried these solutions but dint work. Please check the updated question if it helps to understand more.